# How do class features interact in Gestalt?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, optimization, gestalt

Under the [Gestalt rules](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/gestaltCharacters.htm), how does class features of one "side" affect the class features of the other?

To illustrate the question, and in my specific case, let us look at a **Wizard 2//Beguiler 2**.

The Wizard class allows the character to summon a familiar, which has the *Share Spells* special ability.

- Can the character *Share* Beguiler spells with their familiar?

At level 2, the Beguiler class gets the feature Cloaked Casting, giving the character +1 to spell DCs in specific circumstances.

- Can the character use this bonus for Wizard spells?

Presume the character later becomes a **Wizard 5/Recaster 1//Beguiler 6**, where the Recaster level gives (among other things) the equivalent of the Eschew Materials feat.

- Would the character be able to cast Beguiler spells with the benefits of the Eschew Materials feat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Gestalt treats most features like multiclassing.

Nothing in gestalt changes the fundamentals of how class features work, other than the parts that were specifically called out in the rules. The parts that are called out are just adjudicating how to handle combining two features of the same type, as two different features simply work.

In general, if it's a class feature that is unique to one of the two classes, it's functionally equivalent to multiclassing:

> In this high-powered campaign variant, characters essentially take two classes at every level, choosing the best aspects of each. The process is similar to multiclassing, except that characters gain the full benefits of each class at each level. if the two classes you choose have aspects that overlap (such as Hit Dice, attack progression, saves, and class features common to more than one class), you choose the better aspect. The gestalt character retains all aspects that don’t overlap.

[The multiclassing rules](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/multiclass.htm) include the callout that things will generally just combine:

> The class abilities from a character’s different classes combine to determine a multiclass character’s overall abilities.

This makes it so your question is really about whether those features work cross-class whether you're gestalt or multiclassing, and there's good news: most features work cross-class and don't care about which class they're from.

### None of those features are class-specific.

Share Spells:

> At the master’s option, he may have any spell (but not any spell-like ability) he casts on himself also affect his familiar. The familiar must be within 5 feet at the time of casting to receive the benefit.

Cloaked Casting:

> Starting at 2nd level, a beguiler's spells become more effective when cast against an unwary foe. You gain a +1 bonus to the spell's save DC when you cast a spell that targets any foe who would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not).

Components (from Recaster):

> At 1st level, you can alter the components required to cast your spells. You can freely ignore normal material components as if you had the Eschew Materials feat (though you cannot ignore the need for an expensive material component or an XP component). As well, once per day per class level, you can apply the benefit of either the Silent Spell or the Still Spell feat to any spell you cast without increasing the level of the spell, specially preparing it ahead of time, or increasing its casting time. As with the Silent Spell feat, you cannot apply this benefit to a bard spell in order to cast it without a verbal component.

None of these features are restricted to the class they're from (unless you take "a beguiler's spells" to mean "a beguiler's *beguiler spells*," and even then it's flavorful description rather than mechanical proscription); there's no inherent restriction that says "a class's bonuses only apply to effects generated from the class by the class providing the bonus" for multiclassing. Spell pools themselves remain separate, but an effect like "add +1 to your spell DCs" will affect all of your spells whether it's coming from a general Spell Focus, a specific class's bonus feat spent on Spell Focus, or a feature like Cloaked Casting.

Comment: In addition to the distinction between “beguiler’s spells” and “beguiler spells” (which honestly might be a little fine to expect from WotC editors), the sentence where that appears is _descriptive_, while the _proscriptive_ text that follows makes no mention of class.