# Could both sides of a multi-caster gestalt use Cleric Spell Access from the Rainbow Servant PrC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, multi-classing, prestige-class, gestalt

The capstone ability of the [Rainbow Servant prestige class](https://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/classes/prestige/general/rainbowservant.shtml) states:

> **Cleric Spell Access**: A 10th-level rainbow servant can learn and cast spells from the cleric list, even if they don't appear on the lists of any spellcasting class he has. Such spells are cast as divine spells if they don't appear on the sorcerer/wizard or bard spell lists. This class feature grants access to the spells, but not extra spells per day. The 10th-level rainbow servant can likewise read scrolls with cleric spells on them and use wands and staffs that contain cleric spells.

(Rainbow servant prestige class description, Complete Divine pg. 56)

I see no reference to limiting the spells being added to any one class, and per [my previous question on class features in gestalt](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203047/how-do-class-features-interact-in-gestalt), it seems that both "sides" of the gestalt would indeed benefit from the Cleric Spell Access class feature.

### First part

Would a [Gestalt](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/gestaltCharacters.htm) Beguiler 6/Rainbow Servant 10//Wizard 16 be able to **both**:

1. cast spells from the cleric list with their *Beguiler* spell slots, and also
2. prepare/cast spells from the cleric list with their *Wizard* spell slots?

Of course, while (arguably) the Beguiler "side" would get the spells automatically, the Wizard "side" would have to copy them from other spellbooks or scrolls. But even if the Beguiler "side" doesn't "get" them automatically (but has to learn them in some way), can both "sides" now cast cleric spells  (some as divine spells), once added to spells known?

### Second part

Here, we assume that:

- The Wizard "side" now can "learn and cast spells from the cleric list"
- The Beguiler "side" can, at least through Advanced Learning, get access to cleric spells

And here comes the next step; could the character use the Scribe Scroll feat to **write down** spells known as a Beguiler, *including* spells from the cleric spell list, onto scrolls to be **copied into** the Wizard spellbook?

> **[Scribe Scroll](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#scribeScroll)**
>
> Benefit: You can create a scroll of any spell that you know. [...]

> **[Spells Copied from Another’s Spellbook or a Scroll](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/arcaneSpells.htm#spellsCopiedfromAnothersSpellbookoraScroll)**
>
> A wizard can also add a spell to her book whenever she encounters one on a magic scroll or in another wizard’s spellbook. [...]

Comment: I ask these two questions as one SE question, since they would always be applicable together; I could separate them into two separate SE questions if that is the consensus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First part: Yes, both sides get the feature at once

Your previous question is answered correctly, and does indeed apply here. Nothing about cleric spell access has you choosing one particular class for it, so it applies to all classes.

#### Second part: Yes, assuming some way for the beguiler to learn them

It is not entirely clear how, if at all, a beguiler can learn spells via cleric spell access. But assuming they can one way or another...

A beguiler with Scribe Scroll can create a scroll of any spell they know—if allowed to learn cleric spells with cleric spell access (whether all of them or just a select few through advanced learning), those would be included.

A wizard can copy any arcane scroll into their spellbook, and (if it is a wizard spell and they have a spell slot for it) prepare and cast it. Cleric spell access adds cleric spells to both of those activities, since it allows the wizard to learn, cast, and use scrolls of those spells. And copying a scroll does not care who scribed it, it can be a beguiler or a sorcerer or whatever, just so long as it is arcane (or the wizard can otherwise learn it). It does not matter if you’re dealing with two separate individuals, a beguiler and a wizard, or a single individual who is a multiclass beguiler/wizard or gestalt beguiler//wizard.

Comment: +1, and I'll give you one more argument to consider in interpreting Cleric Spell Access; It explicitly says the character can "cast these spells", which to a spontaneous caster could be interpreted to mean it doesn't matter whether or not the spells are "on their spell list", they can still cast them...maybe? ;)

Comment: @From The exact phrase is “learn and cast” the spells, suggesting that there is a process between them (which, of course, there is, normally). I suppose it could be read your way, but it’s a pretty weak case, particularly if you consider context. The description of the rainbow servant does say “More sorcerers than wizards take on the mantle of the rainbow servant, because access to cleric domains is a compelling goal when spells known are otherwise so limited,” but it focuses on the domains—you’d think they’d mention you get _the entire spell list_ at 10th if that’s what you got.

Comment: For the second part, it says they are "Such spells are cast as divine spells if they don't appear on the sorcerer/wizard or bard spell list".  Wouldn't that imply that a scroll written by an arcane caster with one of these spells would in fact be a divine scroll?

Comment: @Alan Probably! (Can’t say for absolutely sure, though.) I had a whole write-up about how that could be a problem... but on reconsidering, I decided that when cleric spell access says you “can learn” these spells, it covers that for the wizard.

Comment: And this is why I'm confused as to why anyone would keep playing 3.5 when pathfinder 1E is available :)

Comment: @Alan I’m confused why you think PF1e is any better; its wording is, on the whole, sloppier, and its material arguably less balanced. It inherited nearly all of 3.5e’s problems (the only significant exceptions are paladins and polymorphing, which were both greatly improved), and then added its own on top. PF2e is much better in a lot of ways, because it throws out the 3.5e base and all of its myriad problems, and because, frankly, better authors were in charge of it, though it still has issues with sloppiness.